# Databricks Azure Blob Storage access

Tags: azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-authentication

I am trying to access files stored in Azure blob storage and have followed the documentation linked below:

https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/azure-storage.html

I was successful in mounting the Azure blob storage on dbfs but it seems that the method is not recommended anymore. So, I tried to set up direct access using URI using SAS authentication.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<token>")
```

Now when I try to access any file using:

```
spark.read.load("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>")
```

I get the following error:

```
Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.", 403, HEAD,
```

I am able to mount the storage account using the same SAS token but this is not working.
What needs to be changed for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using blob storage, then you have to use `wasbs` and not `abfss`. I have tried using using the same code as yours with my `SAS` token and got the same error with my blob storage.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<token>")

df = spark.read.load("abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/input/sample1.csv")
```

[image]

- When I used the following modified code, I was able to successfully read the data.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")


spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net", "<token>")

df = spark.read.format("csv").load("wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/input/sample1.csv")
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To access files from azure blob storage where the firewall settings are `only from selected networks`, you need to configure `VNet` for the Databricks workspace.

[image]

- Now add the same virtual network to your storage account as well.

[image]

- I have also selected `service endpoints` and `subnet delegation` as following:

[image]

- Now when I run the same code again using the file path as `wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`, the file is read successfully.

[image]

Comment: I get the following error: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container <container> in account <storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them  in the configuration

Comment: Try changing the access level to `Container` access level. Go to storage account, select container, click on change access level and change it to `Container`. This is a [reference image](https://i.imgur.com/NBy0IwJ.png)

Comment: Also, use the path in this format while using spark.read `wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`. Use `blob` and not `dfs`.

Comment: Seems to be an firewall access issue

Comment: Is your blob open for all networks or only selected networks?

Comment: Selected networks, it is firewalled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249096/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-tarique).